# Add multiple columns with zero values from a list to a Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a data frame

```
id col1 col2
1  1    foo
2  1    bar
```

And a list of column names

```
l = ['col3', 'col4', 'col5']
```

How do I add new columns to the data frame with zero as values?

```
id col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1  1    foo     0    0    0
2  1    bar     0    0    0
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You could try direct assignment (assuming your dataframe is named df):

```
for col in l:
    df[col] = 0
```

Or use the DataFrame's assign method, which is a slightly cleaner way of doing it if `l` can contain a value, an array or any pandas Series constructor.

```
# create a dictionary of column names and the value you want
d = dict.fromkeys(l, 0)
df.assign(**d)
```

Pandas Documentation on the `assign` method : http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html

Comment: Your `d` can be written more simply as `dict.fromkeys(l, 0)`.  (Warning, though: since we're using a dictionary we aren't guaranteed that the order will be that of `l`.)

Comment: Thanks! change added.

Comment: how would you enforce that the dtype of the colume is int32 instead of float64? I tried `df[col] = int(0)`, and also converting the whole colum with `astype(int)` but it didn't work

Comment: That's strange, it should be enough to do `df[col] = df[col].astype({col: "int32"})`  It would help to post a reproducible example.

Comment: example of using a dictionary to assign to explain https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42101382/pandas-dataframe-assign-arguments

Answer (score 2):

The current accepted answer produced the following warning on my machine (using `pandas=1.4.2`):

```
PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead. To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`
```

I got rid of these warnings by assigning new columns like so instead:

```py
df.loc[:, l] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, provided solutions with `assign` and `df.loc` are pretty slow. And PerformanceWarning appears

I would actually modify existing answer and use something like:

```
d = dict.fromkeys(l, 0)
temp_df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=df.index)

df = pd.concat([df, temp_df], axis=1)
```